# Why isn't my GNU Emacs initializing with tuareg mode?

Tags: macos, emacs, ocaml, tuareg

I'm running on mac os x.
I have a file at /Users/Max/.emacs with this inside:

> (add-to-list 'load-path “/Users/Max/emacs/tuareg-mode/”)
>   (load "tuareg-mode-startup”)

I have a folder at /Users/Max/emacs/tuareg-mode/ with these files inside which I got from tuareg 2.0.6 and extracted to my 'tuareg-mode' folder:

```
>Makefile  
ocamldebug.el  
README  
tuareg-pkg.el  
tuareg.el
```

edit: Got the 2.0.7 files in my 'tuareg-mode' folder instead, here they are:

```
>Makefile  
ocamldebug.el  
README  
tuareg-pkg.el  
tuareg.el  
tuareg-site-file.el
```

The error I'm getting when I open emacs is such:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading
>   `/Users/Max/.emacs':
>
> Symbol's value as variable is void: “/Users/Max/emacs/tuareg-mode/”
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with the
>   `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

Starting emacs with the --debug-init option gives me this:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable
>   “/Users/Max/emacs/tuareg-mode/”)   (add-to-list (quote load-path)
>   “/Users/Max/emacs/tuareg-mode/”)   eval-buffer(# nil
>   "/Users/Max/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 57
>   load-with-code-conversion("/Users/Max/.emacs" "/Users/Max/.emacs" t t)
>   load("~/.emacs" t t)   #[0
>   "\205\262 \306=\203\307\310Q\202; \311=\204\307\312Q\202;\313\307\314\315#\203*\316\202;\313\307\314\317#\203:\320\nB\321\202;\316\322\323\322\211#\210\322=\203a\324\325\326\307\327Q!\"\323\322\211#\210\322=\203`\210\203\243\330!\331\232\203\243\332!\211\333P\334!\203}\211\202\210\334!\203\207\202\210\314\262\203\241\335\"\203\237\336\337#\210\340\341!\210\266\f?\205\260\314\323\342\322\211#)\262\207"
>   [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file
>   inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs"
>   windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$"
>   "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" (initialization "`_emacs' init
>   file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'") "~/_emacs" t load
>   expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d"
>   file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p
>   file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for
>   1 "default"] 7 "\n\n(fn)"]()   command-line()   normal-top-level()

I'm new Mac OS and completely new to OCaml. I don't see what I've done wrong. Why can't it load the path?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you want `(load "/Users/Max/emacs/tuareg-mode/tuareg-mode-startup.el")` - beware of the double quotes!

Comment: Where exactly am I supposed to find this tuareg-mode-startup.el file? All the files that I downloaded in the 2.0.6 package are listed above in my question

Comment: Remove the trailing backslash from the path in your `load-path`.

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: I found out there was a new version of tuareg (2.0.7) so I downloaded it and replaced the contents of the 'tuareg-mode' folder with the files in 2.0.7  

Still the same error

Comment: I had to load a certain file directly like Basile suggested, 'tuareg-site-file.el'. I'm having a problem now with ocaml. I'm not sure where to download it for mac. I thought I downloaded it and installed it but it's saying it can't find it.

Comment: @user3245760, that's a different question and should be posted separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the correct quotes.

Strings must be surrounded by plain ascii "" quotes.

Otherwise the lisp reader will happily treat them as part of a symbol name, which is why it's treating `“/Users/Max/emacs/tuareg-mode/”` as a variable.

This:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/Max/emacs/tuareg-mode/")
(load "tuareg-mode-startup")
```

Not:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path “/Users/Max/emacs/tuareg-mode/”)
(load "tuareg-mode-startup”)
```

Comment: That makes it much more clear, thanks. Now when I try and run ocaml within tuareg it says it cannot find it. I assume I need to set up paths or something, but I don't know where they are? I think my ocaml was saved to "usr/..." something but I can't even find that folder on my drive.

Comment: What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Well one is ascii character 34 -- `"` -- which, to the elisp reader, denotes the beginning or end of a string literal, and which is generated when you type the `"` key on your keyboard. The other is some unicode character -- `“` -- which has no special meaning to elisp at all. If you just mean that you can't *see* a difference between the two, that's a problem with your web browser or your selected font.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a recent version of Emacs, I strongly recommend using `package.el` to install packages. It will take care of putting things in the right place for you. `package.el` ships with Emacs 24, and there is [a version that you can install for Emacs 23](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs.git;a=blob_plain;hb=ba08b24186711eaeb3748f3d1f23e2c2d9ed0d09;f=lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el).

Once you have `package.el` installed, you can install packages using `M-x package-list-packages` or `M-x package-install`. From the former, find a package you wish to install, mark it with `i`, and apply the marked actions with `x`.

Out of the box, `package.el` only gives you access to the GNU ELPA (Emacs Lisp Package Archive), which doesn't have very many packages. But there are third-party repositories that contain a lot more. I recommend using [MELPA stable](http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/#/), which [does provide `tuareg`](http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/#/tuareg). Something like this should get you started:

```lisp
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
```

There are other cool things you can do with `package.el` as well. If you're interested, I recommend checking out [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) in particular.

See [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA) for more.